# How to keep specific old kernel on my next kernel upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I just updated my Ubuntu 14.04 and got a new kernel. This new kernel is not working properly for me so I booted the previous version. Let's call this good old working version "3.13.0-24.47".

Now, I want to keep this "3.13.0-24.47" version until I decide to delete it manually. I want to be able to upgrade my kernel each time there is a new version in hope of getting the one which works again. Until then, I want to use the "3.13.0-24.47".

I'm afraid that next update will delete my "3.13.0-24.47" version because there are only two kernel versions available at a given time on my system (/boot).

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu-or-free-sp) help you?

Comment: I saw that post and many others. They all talk about removing old versions, not keeping. The best that I found was /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal script which generates list of kernels that must be kept. I could change this script, but what if the script gets updated at some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can be confident that your -24 kernel is not going to be overwritten, since the kernel version has been bumped to -27 now.

To be on the safe side, however, you can use any one of the methods described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) to lock package `linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic`.

Comment: Yes, -27 is the new one on my system. What when -29 comes along? Wont I loose -24? Also, won't pinning the package prevent me from upgrading to -29?

Comment: Normally, no. The only reason you could lose your -24.47 is if a newer -24 (say, -24.49) comes along, then it would overwrite your -24.47. Locking it will prevent that.

Comment: According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/923876/comments/8), Apt will never automatically remove the currently-running kernel, so as long as your -24 is running, you should be fine.

Comment: It seeems that you are right. apt won't remove currently booted version. See comment for /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal

Comment: You still need to lock it if you want to keep your -24.47, however. Because if -24.49 comes along, as far as Apt is concerned -24.47 will not be *removed*, it will be *upgraded*.

Comment: I locked the -24 version. I will keep an eye on this and see if it will upgrade -27 (which is desirable).

Comment: Yes, the lock only applies to -24. If a new -27 (or a -29) is released, you will get it.

Answer (score -2):

While Booting Press `Shift`long it's shows grub and boot from old kernel.

1. when loged in type `Uname-r`i will show to current kernel running in your system.
2. now type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` it shall show all kernels in your system.
3. `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-X.XX.XX.XX-generic` replace x.xx.xxx with the kernel    which u want to remove.

REMEMBER:- Do not Remove current kernel.